# Elastic Search Scroll API effect on CPU

Tags: elasticsearch, scroll, cpu

What is the effect of scroll API on the CPU utilization of a node? I am  experiencing high CPU utilization for scroll API on `ES version 6.2`.

Even though the query is done once to fetch all the data, and then the data is fetched using `scroll_id`, we experience CPU spikes.

Also where does the cached result is stored? In memory or on disk?

Answer (score 1):

You should clear your scroll "pointer" after usage.

> Search context are automatically removed when the scroll timeout has
>   been exceeded. However keeping scrolls open has a cost, as discussed
>   in the previous section so scrolls should be explicitly cleared as
>   soon as the scroll is not being used anymore using the clear-scroll
>   API:

As describe [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-search-context)

> Normally, the background merge process optimizes the index by merging
>   together smaller segments to create new bigger segments, at which time
>   the smaller segments are deleted. This process continues during
>   scrolling, but an open search context prevents the old segments from
>   being deleted while they are still in use. This is how Elasticsearch
>   is able to return the results of the initial search request,
>   regardless of subsequent changes to documents.

So if y understand well there is no cache. It's just that segments that are targeted by your query are frozen until your scroll expires. As segment are immutable in Lucene it ensures that you will have consistent results and that you will be able to scroll all the data that existed when you created the scroll. But the drawback is as long your scroll "pointer" exists, the targeted segments will be kept open and not deleted.

So the number of opened segments will keep increasing, and the necessary files handlers will also be increasing. So on a wide query and particularly if you are indexing in the same time it can lead to performance issues.
Since when you index, you create a lot of small segments that should be merged afterward, but if you do a scroll query on them, they cant be fully merged and deleted.

Are you indexing continuously and how long is your scroll duration ?

[From documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#_clear_scroll_api)

Comment: Ok noted. Will be implementing that as a first optimization.  Will you be able to help me understand where does cache gets stored in case of scroll api ?                And also if I am using slicing in scrolled data, does it mean cache contain as well will be spitted across shards ? and is is on all the shards i.e. primary and replica or just replica if thats the case.   Or if it is stored as physical storage on node or in memory.

Comment: For the cache, I just don't know yet :( and I never used the slices with scroll api, sorry. Keep us posted for the CPU spikes after implementing the clear-scroll.

Comment: Ok. Sure will do it. Where does the scroll data resides is still a mystery.

Comment: We are using ClearScroll. Still the memory does not comes down after using scroll query. Using Elastic Search 7.9 and using NEST 7. Any help would be more welcome @PierreMallet